# Why did this question get migrated?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration, deleted-posts

The question *[What is the moment when all oscillators aligned to make a jump called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/437435/80007)*  was migrated without my knowledge. It seems perfectly fine on this site. The consequence is that it got rejected and therefore automatically deleted, even though it had 2 upvotes.

I'm also not sure why it was closed for being unclear.

> **closed** as unclear what you're asking
>   Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

<sup>Related:

• [The Community user deleted my question! What gives? - Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

• [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/260800)</sup>

Comment: I think your outrage is probably better directed at the site which migrated your question here. It's actually better asked on a specialist site, which you appear to have chosen well.

Comment: "Outrage"? I wonder why you see that? Anyway, didn't that I originally asked that question here, then it got migrated to [dsp.se] then got rejected?

Comment: On DSP it [shows](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/47970/revisions) "Migrated away to ELU"; it got closed here as unclear and currently shows as "Migration rejected" on DSP, which is what happens to migrated questions which are closed on the target site.

Comment: oh I see. So any close reason on the target site will get the question automatically be deleted, even when it has upvotes and answers? Why is that?

Comment: I think this issue has come up before in declined migrations between EL&U and ELL. Unfortunately, it leaves something of a mess behind that even moderators can't clean up properly.

Comment: Yeah this is messed up. There's not even a vote to undelete choice. It may well be a technical vocabulary item more appropriate at sap or physics, but that shouldn't delete it automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the important parts of the timeline:

- You asked [the question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/47970) on Signal Processing.
- You got [an answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47974) there.
- You left the following comment on said answer:

  - > [...] If you think there is no word for this, I think this question is better suited in [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- Peter K., a moderator on Signal Processing, [migrated the question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/47970/revisions) to ELU. (Whether this was due to your comment or something else only he can answer.) Nobody else on that site voted to close or migrate (otherwise their names would be listed).
- On ELU, the question attracted [many comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jljc.png), none of which were from the people who close voted. One person, however, said that it would be "better asked" on another site and suggested the math or physics site. In my opinion, the close reason "unclear what you're asking" can probably be taken at face value—anyone who hasn't seen [an animation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fourier_series_square_wave_circles_animation.gif) probably won't know what you're talking about.
- The question was closed on ELU, which rejected the migration, causing the ELU copy to be locked, and the Signal Processing one to be unlocked. A month later the question (again, on ELU) was deleted by [Roomba](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) because it was "more than 30 days old, and ... it was migrated *from* a different site, and then [rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)". Unfortunately, because the question here is locked, only a moderator can do anything with it.

Hopefully the above explains what happened. The next obvious step in this case, since it looks like some terminology request questions have been well-received on Signal Processing (examples: [1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46601), [2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/47207)), is to see if it really is off-topic there (which seems to be [exactly what you're doing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1574)). If not, then you can flag for a moderator here for it (and all the answers) to be unlocked and undeleted. At that point it could be edited and reopened by you and other regular users.

Comment: thank you for your input. Why is the the posts in both sites are locked? They should at best be closed only, right?

Comment: @Ooker The one on DSP is unlocked. It's only the one on ELU that's locked, to avoid having two copies unlocked at once.

Comment: so there must be one post unlocked at a time? So if I want the ELU one be undeleted and open, then the DSP one must be locked?

Comment: @Ooker A moderator on ELU could unlock the question without affecting the question on DSP by [clearing the migration history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268198/323179). Whether they will is another story of course ;)

Comment: thanks for your effort. I just wonder, why do you spend so much time for me? :D

Comment: @Ooker I probably just have too much time on my hands in general... :P

Comment: @MrLister the question on Signal Processing was never deleted. I was talking about the version on ELU which is still deleted so you can’t see it without 10k rep. (There’s not much to see there anyway but I do have a link to a screenshot of all the comments in my answer.)